# Audio Works Only When Microphone Does Not- Issue with Headset

Tags: sound, usb, microphone, headset

I recently bought a  Plantronics .Audio 655 USB Multimedia Headset. I downloaded the necessary updates for the headset on a Windows computer. The headset worked well on that computer, as both the microphone and audio functioned. When the headset was used on a Linux computer the first time, I found that the microphone worked briefly(several seconds) then stopped. Only the audio worked. I unplugged the headset and inserted it in another USB port. Again, both the microphone and audio worked briefly, but then the audio stopped. Is there a way to fix this?
Thank you for any help in advance.

Specifications

OS: Ubuntu 14.04 AMD64

Memory: 6GB

Graphics: Intel® Sandybridge Mobile

Processor:Intel® Core™ i5-2430M CPU @ 2.40GHz × 4

Answer (score 0):

- You can use Pulse audio volume control (pavucontrol , install it eventually ) : 
  especially in the input devices tab, try to make usb mic the default device with the corresponding button. Also see "configuration" tab and test other profiles  .
- If no luck, use Alsamixer (https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Audio/Alsamixer) to tweak mic settings . (press F6 select usb device)